# Comparing columns within the same group

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison

My data frame:

```
data <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), col1 = c(9, 
9.05, 7.15, 7.21, 7.34, 8.12, 7.5, 7.84, 7.8, 7.52, 8.84, 6.98, 
6.1, 6.89, 6.5, 7.5, 7.8, 5.5, 6.61, 7.65, 7.68), col2 = c(11L, 
11L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L), col3 = c(7L, 11L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 
5L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 2L), 
    col4 = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 
    11L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 11L), col5 = c(11L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 
    8L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

I have a function that compares columns in each group. I would like it to compare not all columns with each other, but only those that I select.

Now the function compares:(2-3;2-4;2-5;2-6;3-4;3-5;3-6;4-5;4-6;5-6)

I want to set this order myself, for example:(2-4;3-5;4-6)

Function:

```
wilcox.fun <- function(dat) { 
  do.call(rbind, combn(names(dat), 2, function(x) {
    test <- wilcox.test(dat[[x[1]]], dat[[x[2]]], paired=TRUE)
    data.frame(Test = sprintf('Group %s by Group %s', x[1], x[2]), 
               W = round(test$statistic,4), 
               p = test$p.value)
  }, simplify = FALSE))
}


result <- purrr::map_df(split(data[,c(2,3,4,5,6)], data$group), wilcox.fun, .id = 'Group')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of vectors with the combination that you are interested in. Change the `combn` in the function which calculates every combination to `lapply` which will calculate only for specific combinations that we defined and combine the result with `purrr::map_df`.

```
combination <- list(c(2, 4), c(3, 5), c(4, 6))

wilcox.fun <- function(dat) { 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(combination, function(x) {
    test <- wilcox.test(dat[[x[1]]], dat[[x[2]]], paired=TRUE)
    data.frame(Test = sprintf('Group %s by Group %s', x[1], x[2]), 
               W = round(test$statistic,4), 
               p = test$p.value)
  }))
}

result <- purrr::map_df(split(data, data$group), wilcox.fun, .id = 'Group')
```

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. And can you also tell me if I need to make an offset for the vector (2,3,4) by +2 and compare (2-4;3-5;4-6)?

Comment: Right now 2-4, 3-5, 4-6 correspond to the column numbers in the original `data` so column number 2-4 is `col1-col3`, 3-5 is `col2-col4`. Change the numbers in `combinations` accordingly. To be clear you can also change `combination` from number to name like `combination <- list(c('col1', 'col3'), c('col2','col4'),...etc)` and it should work as well with the same code.

Comment: and could you tell me how to limit the number of groups, for example, a comparison for 1 and 2, and for the third one it is not necessary

Comment: I see that you asked a new question regarding that and already got the answer.